# CentOS wget issues

Tags: ssl, centos, wget

When I use wget I get the following error:

```
 HTTPS support not compiled in.
```

When I try to install wget myself I get:

```
./configure –with-ssl=openssl
configure: error: invalid variable name: `–with-ssl'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo there. Don't use the unicode dash `–with-ssl=openssl`. Use standard ascii two dashes to pass the proper argument `--with-ssl=openssl`.